# Python Extract data from file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file just say

```
text1 text2 text text
text text text text
```

I am looking to firstly count the number of strings in the file (all deliminated by space) and then output the first two texts. (text 1 text 2)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for the help

Edit: This is what I have so far:

```
>>> f=open('test.txt')
>>> for line in f:
    print line
ï»¿text1 text2 text text text text hello
>>> words=line.split()
>>> words
['\xef\xbb\xbftext1', 'text2', 'text', 'text', 'text', 'text', 'hello']
>>> len(words)
7
if len(words) > 2:
    print "there are more than 2 words"
```

The first problem I have is, my text file is: text1 text2 text text text

But when i pull the output of words I get:
['\xef\xbb\xbftext1', 'text2', 'text', 'text', 'text', 'text', 'hello']

Where does the '\xef\xbb\xbf come from?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems did you run into? This is quite basic python, but we can help if you had specific problems with your code.

Comment: updated above in original post

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To read a file line by line, just loop over the open file object in a `for` loop:

```
for line in open(filename):
    # do something with line
```

To split a line by whitespace into a list of separate words, use `str.split()`:

```
words = line.split()
```

To count the number of items in a python list, use `len(yourlist)`:

```
count = len(words)
```

To select the first two items from a python list, use slicing:

```
firsttwo = words[:2]
```

I'll leave constructing the complete program to you, but you won't need much more than the above, plus an `if` statement to see if you already have your two words.

The three extra bytes you see at the start of your file are the [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) (Byte Order Mark); it marks your file as UTF-8 encoded, but it is redundant and only really used on Windows.

You can remove it with:

```
import codecs
if line.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF8):
    line = line[3:]
```

You may want to decode your strings to unicode using that encoding:

```
line = line.decode('utf-8')
```

You could also open the file using [`codecs.open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open):

```
file = codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8')
```

Note that `codecs.open()` will *not* strip the BOM for you; the easiest way to do that is to use `.lstrip()`:

```
import codecs
BOM = codecs.BOM_UTF8.decode('utf8')
with codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.lstrip(BOM)
```

Comment: thanks so much! I was originally working with numpy/ascii module that read files. I am new to python (2nd) day so I will crack away at it and update as I go