# (Python) CSV Reader omits a line

Tags: python, csv

I'm doing a sentiment analysis project.

I have a csv file with the following format:

```
|happy|,|I'm happy|
|sad|,|Today is a bad day|
|angry|,|I hate this|
...
```

A dictionary type variable is declared and used to store the count of different emotion.

```
count = {"happy":0, "sad":0, "angry":0}
```

A function is defined to retrieve the emotion and messages.

```
total_status = 0
inpStatus = csv.reader(open(Filename, 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
for row in inpStatus:
    sentiment = row[0]
    status = row[1]
    total_status += 1
...
    for s in count:
        if (sentiment == s):
            count[s] += 1
```

I found that the first line (i.e. `|happy|,|I'm happy|`) and the last line of the file is skipped in the count. And the `total_status` omits one line.
Did I write the delimiter in a wrong way?
Why does that happen and how should I rewrite the program?

Comment: As I'm doing utf-8 file importing so here is exactly my problem and the solution!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561063/python-extract-data-from-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually I rewrote your code and it works fine:

```
from csv import reader

total_status = 0
count = {'happy': 0, 'sad': 0, 'angry':0}

for sentiment, status in reader(open(filepath, 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|'):
    total_status += 1
    count[sentiment] += 1
```

But your code gives proper result too.

Comment: Oh that's because of my data stored in the csv file..
Thanks for your rewrite anyway!

Comment: This is exactly what I thought. Also, if you need to compute length of the sequence, it would be better to store a reference to it, as you did and simply call len(inp_status), since it is O(1) as far as I know.